# How to send form data in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and html.

I need to send data through post method and like

```
{"username":"user1111","fileNumber":"20120097072286","fileType":"2"}
```

and read the response in Javascript.

If any one know the solution please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jquery AJAX like this:

```
$.post{
  url:,
  data:{},
  success:function(){}
}
```